# Find() with an array as condition : Undefined offset: 1

Tags: cakephp

My aim it to select lines in which `etat_ce` is one of the items in my array.

For some reason I can't find the right syntax in the cookbook for this kind of request.

```
$etat = array('livre', 'partiellement_livre', 'valide');
$out = $this->find('all', array('conditions' => array('etat_ce ' => $etat)));
```

When I do it this way, cake pops me a warning :

> Notice (8): Undefined offset: 1
>   [CORE\Cake\Model\Datasource\DboSource.php, line 2549]

When I keep only one item in the array it works. Is is a problem with my syntax ?

EDIT:  I use cake php ver 2.3.5
Many thanks !

Comment: What kind of field is etat_ce? Enum? Also: you should always mention the exact cakephp version you are using.

Comment: The field etat_ce  is a varchar. Oh and the version of cake I use is 2.3.5. I'll add it to the queston, thanks for the tip !

Comment: Are you sure it is the find() that produces the warning ? Not a post-treatment further in your function ?

Comment: Or a beforFind messing up the query/conditions. Did you try the latest stable 2.3.8 if the issue is gone then?

Comment: Find in cookbook about using OR in find()

Comment: @Chris : Yes I'm positive. Do you want a copy of the callstack ? The most interesting is that the find returns the right lines but always pops this warning.

Comment: @mark : I doubt it, since I have no beforFind defined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

'etat_ce ' => remove the white space? Or try with the model name? 'Modelname.etat_ce'

Answer (score 0):

### The array key has an extra space

If in doubt - [look at the source](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.3.5/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php#L2549):

```
if (strpos($key, ' ') === false) {
    $operator = '=';
} else {
    list($key, $operator) = explode(' ', trim($key), 2);
```

The error is because the key in the conditions array contains a space - as is shown in the question:

```
$out = $this->find('all', array('conditions' => array('etat_ce ' => $etat)));
                                                              ^
```

This is confusing the condition parsing logic, to correct it just remove the space:

```
$out = $this->find('all', array('conditions' => array('etat_ce' => $etat)));
                                                              ^
```

and the error disappears, and the conditions are as expected `Foo.etat_ce = 'whatever'`

Comment: No need, just learn from your mistakes, like accepting a duplicate answer :D

Comment: It's the kind of small mistake you have a really hard time solving when you are too focused on the problem. An exterior person may immediately see the solution, or usually on the next day after a good night's sleep you find the solution yourself in under 10 seconds :)